# jQuery not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a test environment to try to get jquery working in wordpress, the installation version is 3.2.1 and the theme is 2010 (although I have tried this in a few different themes, same result).  There are no plug-ins installed.

Basically I am putting this in the header file to see if I can get jQuery to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

have also tried this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

and this

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict(); 
// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

I can not seem to get it to display the alert when the page loads.  When I check firebug the script has loaded.

jQuery works fine when not used in conjunction with WP and all scripts tested outside of WP perform as expected.

Should it work in WP 3.2.1?  What can I try?

Comment: some frameworks can make your scripts is no working!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The answer below was **not** intended as step-by-step instructions about how to add jQuery to Wordpress.   **I'm simply asking him to check and see if it's already there, then I'm telling him to "not include it again" IF it's already there.**

As mentioned in comments, **[wp_enqueue_script is the absolute best way to add jQuery to Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), whenever you need to add jQuery**.

---

Of course jQuery works within Wordpress but I am not sure if it's already included within the Twenty-Ten theme by default.  Check to see if the script includes tags are there.  You need something like this in the header someplace before you can call any JavaScript that uses jQuery...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
```

**(Make sure you're not including it more than once or multiple versions.)**

Comment: $ cannot be used as replacement for jQuery in Wordpress without doing some jQuery no conflict methods. Also, it's recommended that you use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load in jQuery to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @Paul:  Yes, all good things you mention.  However, I'm not instructing him how to add it... I'm telling him to make sure it's already there and not include it again IF it's already there.

Comment: Did not try $ currently.  THAT WORKED!!  (adding script to source in the jquery.js)  I thought it was loaded by default??  Also should wp_enqueue_script be used or is it OK to just source in the jquery?  IT IS WORKING... although still a bit confused.  OH, just see about the wp_enqueue_script comment.  I will try that although before it did not seem to be working.

Comment: Whenever you add a plugin requiring jQuery, the plugin may add jQuery again, hence the need of using something like the wp_enqueue_script.  I would recommend it.

Comment: OK, the wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); statement added before the head worked.

Comment: @macmiller: You neglected to include the jQuery library and I correctly figured that out first.

Comment: This is totally not the way you include js in jquery! http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

Comment: @Ionut:  Yes, this was already addressed in comments above and as explained, my example is not a coding recommendation.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

Have you added the actual jQuery script file?

There are a number of ways to do this, but I usually use the following method by including this code in the functions.php file.

```
<?php
    function add_jquery() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }    

    add_action('init', 'add_jquery');
?>
```

Here is also a good resource for more jQuery + Wordpress usage: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure WP itself (or another installed plugin) does not have an already embedded jQuery version that conflicts with yours.. View the source of your page and make sure only one jQuery version is loaded. Should go w/o problems.

Answer (score 0):

By using `wp_enqueue_script` you are sure the jQuery library is loaded ONCE. You can see [here](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html) how to load a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the way mentioned by Paul Sham which is absolutely correct, following way is also helpful which is also describe at [THIS](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/) link.

```
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !is_admin()){
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery',       ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.3.1');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
}
```

put this code in your current wordpress theame's function.php file in between

Answer (score 0):

I find the other one, write this at the beginning of your script.
$ = jQuery.noConflict();